# Is formatted output equivalent?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment, postfix-operator

When I was doing the practice questions today, I found that the outputs of `printf("%d\n",x--);` and `printf("%d\n",x);` are the same.

I changed it to `printf("%d\n",x++);` and found to be the same. I want to know why.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x;
   scanf_s(" %d", &x);

   if (x++ > 5)
       printf("%d",x);
   else
       printf("%d\n",x--);

       return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Do you know that the postfix increment/decrement operators return the *old* value (before modification)?

Comment: You probably meant `--x` instead of `x--`. Read closely the parts dealing with post-/prefix operators in your learning material.

Comment: "--x" is an example of an [prefix operation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-increment-and-decrement-operator).  The decrement will occur FIRST, hence you should see the decremented value in the "printf".  "x++", on the other hand, is a "postfix" operation.  Which is the reason you don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You used the post-decrement/-increment operators.

`x--` decrements `x` and returns the original value of `x`.

`x++` increments `x` and returns the original value of `x`.

To get the desired behaviour, use the pre-decrement/-increment operators.

`--x` decrements `x` and returns the modified `x`.

`++x` increments `x` and returns the modified `x`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the
> operand.** As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
> incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
> it)

and

> 3 The postfix -- operator is analogous to the postfix ++ operator,
> except that the value of the operand is decremented (that is, the
> value 1 of the appropriate type is subtracted from it).

Consider this pair of calls of `printf`

```
int x = 10;
printf( "%d\n", x++ ); 
printf( "%d\n", x );
```

The output is

```
10
11
```

That is the value of the expression of `x++` is the value of its operand that is equal to `10`. As a side effect the variable `x` is increased and in the second call of `printf` the new value of `x` after applying the side effect is outputted.

You can imagine this call

```
printf( "%d\n", x++ );
```

like

```
printf( "%d\n", x ), x += 1;
```

Opposite to postfix increment and decrement operators the values of unary increment (`++x`) and decrement (`--x`) operators are values after incrementing and decrementing their operands.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented.
> The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation.

and

> 3 The prefix -- operator is analogous to the prefix ++ operator,
> except that the value of the operand is decremented.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple and you can understand as well if you know the usage of these 2 kind of operators.

> Post Increment/Decrement Operator e.g. `a++`, `a--` etc.
>
> So when we use it in the statement, the current value of the variable will be used and post that its value is incremented by `1`.

Just take a look into my comments at end of statements (shows the o/p).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x;
   scanf_s(" %d", &x); // 10

   printf("%d", x++);  // 10
   printf("%d", x);    // 11
   return 0;
}
```

---

> Pre Increment/Decrement Operator, e.g. `++a`, `--a` etc.
>
> So when we use it in the statement, first its value of variable is incremented by `1` & then the incremented value will be used.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x;
   scanf_s(" %d", &x);   // 10

   printf("%d", ++x);    // 11
   printf("%d", x);      // 11
   return 0;
}
```

I think, now it's clear to you. For info on usages, just take a look into [Usage of Pre/Post Increment & Decrement operators in C](https://www.javatpoint.com/increment-and-decrement-operators-in-c).